# Associative Arrays in Ruby

Tags: ruby, associative-array

Does Ruby have associative arrays?

For eg:

```
   a = Array.new
   a["Peter"] = 32
   a["Quagmire"] = 'asdas'
```

What is the easiest method to create such an data structure in Ruby?

Comment: Its Ruby language, Ruby on rails is a framework built with Ruby.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Unlike PHP which conflates arrays and hashes, in Ruby (and practically every other language) they're a separate thing.

http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html

In your case it'd be:

```
a = {'Peter' => 32, 'Quagmire' => 'asdas'}
```

There are several freely available introductory books on ruby and online simulators etc.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/

Comment: In other words: you have to just replace "`a = Array.new`" with "`a = Hash.new`".

Comment: worth noting that ruby seems to have confused hashes with data structures that use hashes for lookups - e.g. hash table/hash map. in most other contexts these concepts are not confused

Comment: RE: "...[associative] arrays and hashes... in Ruby (and practically every other language) they're a separate thing."  Wikipedia lists a dozen others "like PHP" in this regard (see: "Associative Array") -- not arguing, but it feels like this comment distracts from the answer.

Answer (score 33):

Use hashes, here's some examples on how to get started (all of these do the same thing, just different syntax):

```
a = Hash.new
a["Peter"] = 32
a["Quagmire"] = 'asdas'
```

Or you could do:

```
a = {}
a["Peter"] = 32
a["Quagmire"] = 'asdas'
```

Or even a one liner:

```
a = {"Peter" => 32, "Quagmire" => 'gigity'}
```

Comment: You can also increment as expected; `a["Peter"] += 1` etc.

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, it's interesting to note that Ruby **does** provide [`Array#assoc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-assoc) and [`Array#rassoc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-rassoc) methods that add "hash like lookup" for an array of arrays:

```rb
arr = [
  ['London', 'England'],
  ['Moscow', 'Russia'],
  ['Seattle', 'USA']
]

arr.assoc('Seattle') #=> '['Seattle', 'USA']
arr.rassoc('Russia') #=> ['Moscow', 'Russia']
```

Keep in mind that unlike a Ruby hash where lookup time is a constant `O(1)`, both `assoc` and `rassoc` have a linear time `O(n)`. You can see why this is by having a look at the [Ruby source code on Github for each method.](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/e5c441a4a2885da61df9894ac17b69cb3c5811f2/array.c#L4157)

So, although in *theory* you can use an array of arrays to be "hash like" in Ruby, it's likely you'll only ever want to use the `assoc/rassoc` methods if you are *given* an array of arrays - maybe via some external API you have no control over - and otherwise in almost all other circumstances, using a Hash will be the better route.