# Associated array in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have seen this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266695/ruby-associative-arrays) about associated array in Ruby, and I know, it is completely like php.

But take a look at this piece of code:

```
x=[1,"Jef",:three]
```

it is clear that `x[1]="jef"`, but the question is:
What is the role of `:three`.
I gussed it should be a key with a nill value, and i changed the code to this

```
x=[1,"Jef",:three,4]
```

and when i run it, I faced with this error:

```
no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer (TypeError)
```

so what are the roles of   **:**    and **three** here?

Comment: Read up about ruby [Symbols](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Symbol.html).

Comment: " it is completely like php" - the answers you linked to, they say that's it's _nothing_ like php. So I don't know where you derived this idea from.

Comment: For `x = [555, 'Jeff', :three]`, `x[1]` will still yield `"Jeff"`. How do you explain that? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're confusing arrays with hashes. In this particular example

```
x = [1,"Jef",:three,4]
```

incidently `x[1]` is equal to `"Jef"`, but thats because element at 1st index of `x` is `"jeff"` (which should be obvious as `x` is an [Array](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html)), not because every two elements are key value pairs as in a a [Hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Hash.html).

The error

```
no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer (TypeError)
```

is probably because you tried something like `x[:three]`, which is obviously invalid.

This could  work if your `x` looks something like this.

```
x = { 1 => "Jef", :three => 4 }
```

Then `x[:three]` will result in desired result `4`.

Remember [Arrays](https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1-ruby-primer/chapters/1-arrays/lessons/2-arrays-introduction) and [Hashes](http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1-ruby-primer/chapters/10-hashes-in-ruby/lessons/47-hashes-in-and-out) in Ruby are two different concepts.

`:three` is a [Symbol](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Symbol.html) which are essentially strings with few [twists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621073/when-to-use-symbols-instead-of-strings-in-ruby).

**Suggestion** : If you want to learn basic Ruby stuff you can read up on  [Rubymonk](https://rubymonk.com/). I has great content.

Answer (score 0):

`:three` is a symbol and it's just a regular member of a regular array. Associative arrays in Ruby are something different and they're called hashes.